# How to search tweets with a specific word in a sorted way(latest tweet first)?

Tags: twitter, twitter-search

For example if I enter "stackoverflow" in the search bar, it is displaying all the tweets with word "stackoverflow" but not in sorted way(latest tweet first).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitter has a tab named **Latest** in search results which shows latest result first. See this screenshot for reference:

[image]